# The text in first column of a multirow table is crossing the borders

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\begin{table}[!ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8in}|p{3.5in}|} \hline
Goals & Approaches\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{STRU Mathematical Modeling} & Empirical studies for loop       classification\\\cline{2-2}
                       & Category-based loop modeling \\\cline{2-2}
     & Segmented dynamic analysis \\\hline\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{STRU Path Analysis}         & Taint analysis to find input- and secret-controlled loops  \\\cline{2-2} 
                                                 & Graph compaction with path equivalence classes                   \\\cline{2-2}
                       & Inter-procedural, demand-driven, path-sensitive, symbolic analysis to determine complexity   \\\hline\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{**Demand-driven, Composable Analysis**} & Analysis accuracy boundary identifier   \\\cline{2-2}      
                                                                 & Dynamic analysis and {\it fc-vector} summary for library calls  \\\cline{2-2}
                                                                 & Type inference for dynamic dispatching problems \\\hline\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Analysis for Intelligence Amplification} & eXtensible Common Software Graph (XCSDG) based visualization \\\cline{2-2}
                                                                            & Graph query language  \\\cline{2-2}
                                                                            & Demand-driven based scripting for quickly constructing semantic analysis based on the human needs\\\hline

\end{tabul    \end{table}
```

In the above tex code the text in the first column of my table is crossing the border, how can I rectify this?One way is to increase the width of but that is not a permanent solution, as I want  the text int he first column to start in a new line if it reaches the table border!
[image]
Screen Shot:

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51568/32374

Comment: `multrow`'s `*` is like `l` you need to give it a length `2.8in` here

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into using a `tabularx` environment instead of the basic `tabular` environment to start organizing the table's structure. Start by setting the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`. Next, because it looks like the terms in the left-hand column shouldn't suffer line breaks, use the `l` column type for it. For the right-hand column, use (a modified form of) the `X` column type. That way, LaTeX will calculate the width of the column for you.

I wouldn't use the `multirow` package and its `\multirow` macro for this table. I would also get rid of the three vertical lines and load the `booktabs` package to draw well-spaced horizontal lines. E.g., I would replace all `\hline\hline` directives with `\midrule` and all `\cline{2-2}` instructions with `\cmidrule(l){2-2}. If you look closely at the image below, you'll notice that the lines drawn by`\toprule`and`\bottomrule`are thicker than`\midrule`which is, in turn, thicker than`\cmidrule`. In contrast,`\hline`and`\cline` both create lines of the same thickness. (By the way, if it were my own table, I'd also get rid of these horizontal lines as well and replace them with a bit of vertical whitespace. However, you seem to have a liking for plenty of horizontal lines, so I didn't purge them from the example.)

I'd also suggest using `\small` instead of `\footnotesize` unless your document is really, really pressed for space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % Ragged-Right form of "X" column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l Y @{} } 
\toprule
Goals & Approaches\\
\midrule
STRU Mathematical Modeling 
& Empirical studies for loop classification\\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Category-based loop modeling \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Segmented dynamic analysis \\
\midrule
STRU Path Analysis 
& Taint analysis to find input- and secret-controlled loops  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Graph compaction with path equivalence classes \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Inter-procedural, demand-driven, path-sensitive, symbolic analysis to determine complexity   \\
\midrule
**Demand-driven, Composable Analysis** 
& Analysis accuracy boundary identifier   \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Dynamic analysis and \emph{fc-vector} summary for library calls  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Type inference for dynamic dispatching problems \\
\midrule
Analysis for Intelligence Amplification 
& eXtensible Common Software Graph (XCSDG) based visualization \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Graph query language  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
& Demand-driven based scripting for quickly constructing semantic analysis based on the human needs\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```